# $f_{n}(x) = \cos (\frac{x}{n})$ converges uniformly to $f(x) = 1$ for $x \in [0,\pi]$. Why?

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that the sequence of functions $$f_{n}(x) = \cos \left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$$ converges uniformly to $$f(x) = 1\text{ for } x \in  [0,\pi].$$

Comment: ${}{}\cos 0 = 1$

Comment: $|f_{n}(x)-f(x)| = |1-cos (\frac{x}{n})| = |2sin^2(\frac{x}{2n})|$

and since $sin \theta \leq \theta$ for $\theta \in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$

$|2sin^2(\frac{x}{2n})|$ $\leq$ $2(\frac{x}{2n})^2$ $\leq$ $\frac{\pi^2}{2n^2}$

Hence $|f_{n}(x)-f(x)| < \epsilon$ provided $n> max(1, \frac{\pi}{\sqrt(2\epsilon)})$

Is this correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to see that the sequence $(f_n)$ is pointwise convergent to the function $f$ where $f(x)=1$ for all $x\in[0,\pi]$. Moreover the function 
$$x\mapsto f_n(x)$$
is decreasing on the interval $[0,\pi]$ hence
$$\sup_{x\in[0,\pi]}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\sup_{x\in[0,\pi]}\left(1-\cos\left(\frac xn\right)\right)=1-\cos\left(\frac\pi n\right)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$$
hence the given sequence is uniformly convergent to $f$.